# Cannot build apk with Jenkins using androidx libraries

Tags: android, jenkins, android-support-library, androidx

Since I migrate to androidx my app, I've got an error on Jenkins when I launch the task assemble. This is error:

```
Program type already present: 
android.support.v4.app.INotificationSideChannel$Stub$Proxy
```

But I don't have this error on Android Studio, I can build the apk without any problem.

So, I tried to exclude the support-v4 module from the google play services:

```
implementation( "com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:16.0.0"){
    exclude module: 'support-v4'
}
implementation ("com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:16.0.0"){
    exclude module: 'support-v4'
}
implementation ("com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:16.0.0"){
    exclude module: 'support-v4'
}
```

Then the apk is generate but on start the app I've got this error:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroid/support/v4/util/ArraySet;
   at com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.c.<init>(Unknown Source:45)
   at com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.c.a(Unknown Source:33)
   at com.google.android.gms.common.api.e.<init>(Unknown Source:51)
   at com.google.android.gms.common.api.e.<init>(Unknown Source:13)
   at com.google.android.gms.location.b.<init>(Unknown Source:8)
   at com.google.android.gms.location.f.a(Unknown Source:2)
```

But once again, everything work fine on Android studio, the problem is only on Jenkins since a migrate to Androidx.

Thanks for your help

Comment: Please show your gradle file

Comment: Also a stacktrace would be helpful to understand what is trying to use `ArraySet`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Jenkins is not using the gradle.properties file that has the androidx parameters:

```
android.enableJetifier=true
android.useAndroidX=true
```

This is why is working on the local machine but on Jenkins.

Comment: is there a way to make jenkins use this gradle.properties file?

Comment: @AmineG I did not find a way to make jenkins user this gradle file but what I've done is to pass those parameters in the `gradle :app:assemble` task separating each key with a -P between each parameter. `gradle :app:ProRelease -Pandroid.enableJetifier=true -Pandroid.useAndroidX=true` Let me know if you need more help.